# Post Request to WebService in Android

Tags: java, android, .net, json, wcf

I have a problem with a WebService on Android. I am getting a 400 error but there is no information on the ErrorStream.

What I am trying to do is a POST request on a WCF Webservice using JSON.

I must add that I have `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` Enabled on my Service. The last time I got a 400 error, it was because I hadn't defined the `RequestProperty`. Now I don't get any error in the stream.

Here is the code:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
      // In my last error I had not included these lines. Maybe they are still wrong?
      urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

      urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
      urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

      OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

      OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
      outputStreamWriter.write(jsonObject.toString(), 0, jsonObject.length());
      outputStreamWriter.flush();
      //outputStreamWriter.close();

      int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println(code);

      if(code == 400) {
            BufferedInputStream errorStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
            InputStreamReader errorStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(errorStreamReader);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String aux = "";

            while ((aux = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  builder.append(aux);
            }
            String output = builder.toString(); // The output is empty.
            System.out.print(output);
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library from Square it's more easy and thin for GET/POST request and especially for REST. I suggest you to try it. It will make your life easy.
You can use different JSON parsers, error handlers, etc. Very flexible.

POST request definition using retrofit it's simple like this:

An object can be specified for use as an HTTP request body with the @Body annotation.

```
@POST("/users/new")
void createUser(@Body User user, Callback<User> cb);
```

Methods can also be declared to send form-encoded and multipart data.

Form-encoded data is sent when @FormUrlEncoded is present on the method. Each key-value pair is annotated with @Field containing the name and the object providing the value.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/user/edit")
User updateUser(@Field("first_name") String first, @Field("last_name") String last);
```

After you define method inside your Java interface like shown above instantiate it:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.soundcloud.com")
    .build();

MyInterface service = restAdapter.create(MyInterface.class);
```

And then you can call your method synchronously or asynchronously (in case you pass Callback instance).

```
service.myapi(requestBody);
```

See Retrofit documentation (http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/index.html) and samples on GitHub for more details.

Comment: I will look at it and give you a response.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to implement a POST request with retrofit? I can only find GET requests.

Comment: Also check OkHTTP library (for networking) from same Square team. It can be used alone or easily integrated with Retrofit or Picasso libraries. It handle difference between default Android network clients and also has features like: response cache, GZIP compression, connection reuse (pooling), etc.

Comment: How do you call the method synchronously? Thanks for the answer, I think this is the way to go. I want to make the application wait until the action is finished. Maybe with a ProgressDialog.

Comment: In example above I show how to call it synchronously. But be aware of doing ANY network operation in application MAIN (UI) thread, in new OS version you will get NetworkOnMainThreadException. 
By Android guideline you have to execute this operation in background thread. Retrofit RestAdapter.Builder has setExecutors method to set ThreadPool for assync request execution. Read docs.
Also if you wanna wait until request will finish set your code inside Callback passed to request method that's all. When you define request with Callback param it became assync and callback will be fired when job done

Answer (score 0):

A 400 error might be occuring (and usually occurs in my case) because of incorrect URL or bad JSON format in post. please check those two

Using an HttpPost object will make your job a lot easier in my opinion

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    if(payload != null){
        try {
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload,HTTP.UTF_8);
            entity.setContentType(contentType);
            post.setEntity(entity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "post err url : " + url);
            LOG.e(TAG, "post err url" , e);
            throw new Exception(1, e);
        }
    }

    HttpResponse response=executeRequest(owner, post);
```